# Does a family of seminorm induce by a vector space isomorpism turn one of this vector space into a frechet space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Suppose $F$ is a Frechet  space induced by a family of seminorms $P$. Now let $V$ be another vector space which is isomorphic to $F$ by $\tau: V \rightarrow F $. We define family of seminorms $K$ on  $V$ by
$$k_i=p_i\circ\tau$$

where $k_i \in K$ and $p_i \in P$

My question is , does this family of seminorms $K$ turn $V$ in a Frecht space?

Comment: What happens when you try to prove this?

Comment: @GEdgar  I prooved it by  but I am not sure of my proof

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/ on how to ask a question here.